# How do I manipulate a datetime variable imported from Excel into R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am importing multiple Excel sheets to R using `readxl`.  Each of these sheets contains observations of transactions which include `DateOfEvent` and `TimeOfEvent` fields.

When I import the time field, R converts it to a POSIXct object based on the date being from Excel Day 0 - i.e. `1899-12-31 0:0:0`

e.g. `dat <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+0:1, time=as.POSIXct(c(10,11), origin="1899-12-31"))`

With the data in a data frame, using a `dplyr` step to clean my data, how would I -

- Use `lubridate` to recode the date part of the variable using the DateOfEvent value?
- Keep the times but make them independent of date so that I can compare events occurring in time buckets across different days (i.e. drop the 1899 date but format the date so that I can perform cross day comparisons)?

Comment: Can you provide a couple of example rows? Does something like: `dat <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+0:1, time=as.POSIXct(c(10,11), origin="1899-12-31"))` cover your circumstance? If so, edit it in to your question.

Comment: Yes; that will provide a suitable sample.  I will amend the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `update()` to change the year in `time`.
Use [`hms::as.hms()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hms/hms.pdf) if you want to extract just the time object from `time` (this will convert to UTC):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(time = update(time, 
                       year = year(date), 
                       month = month(date), 
                       day = day(date)),
         hms = hms::as.hms(time))

        date                time      hms
1 2018-06-02 2018-06-02 16:00:10 23:00:10
2 2018-06-03 2018-06-03 16:00:11 23:00:11
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew - that's what I am after.

It is a shame that lubridate update fctn does not accept a whole date, rather than having to break out to year, month, day - e.g. update(time, date = date(DateX)).